# save data in mysql by stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, timeout

i have a table that must by update  every month, due i upload text file on server and save it in temporary table, the bellow code show it:

```
$result_emp = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'".$myFile_emp."' INTO TABLE infemptemp COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','";
```

then after update successfully and insert new data in "infemptem" table, i should compare the data of main table's "infemp" that have old data by "infemptemp"  that have new data, for do this Scenario i write bellow code:

```
$viwe_emp =mysqli_query($conn,"select * from infempsame where 1");
              $NumRows_emp=mysqli_num_rows($viwe_emp);
              //echo $NumRows_vam;
              $i=0;

              while(($row=$viwe_emp->fetch_assoc())!=NULL)
                {
                $prsid1=$row['PrsID'];
                $AccID1=$row['AccID'];
                $numid1=$row['NumID'];
                $sql2="select * from infempsame  where prsID='".$prsid1."';";
                if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql2))
                    {
                    $sql2_update="UPDATE `infemp` SET AccID='".$AccID1."',NumID='".$numid1."' WHERE prsID='".$prsid1."';";
                     if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql2_update))
                     {
                     $i+=1;
                     }
                    }// end   if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql2))

          }// end while insert new fields of infvam
```

by attention to the code and have 3500 record in "infempsame " table on my database, when i want update "infemp" table, the time out on browser occur.
I think if write above code by procedure, my problem solved.
Is it true? How do i can write procedure and call or use it?
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stored procedure would be overkill. There is a better way hidden away but it get's only a very brief mention in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

> You can also perform UPDATE operations covering multiple tables.
>   However, you cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT with a multiple-table
>   UPDATE. The table_references clause lists the tables involved in the
>   join. Its syntax is described in Section 13.2.9.2, “JOIN Syntax”. Here
>   is an example:

```
UPDATE items,month SET items.price=month.price WHERE
items.id=month.id;
```

Thus you can write a simple query to get rid of the PHP script like this.

```
UPDATE infemp, infemptemp 
    SET infemp.AccID=infemptemp.AccID,
    infemp.NumID=infemptemp.numID 
WHERE infemp.prsID=infemptemp.prsID;
```

if you have an index on the prsID column this should complete very quickly.

Comment: Hi Dear, thanks so much, It solve my problem, Your answer change my view toward sql clause and use them in programming.